# Convert all letters to uppercase except those following a backslash

Tags: python, regex, string

I have the following 8 bit hex string `\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\n!\x1c`
The desired output is `'\x00\x13\xA2\x00@\n!\x1C'`

I need to do this by changing the all letters to caps except for those following a `\`

I tried to do this by making the entire string into Caps and making the N's and X's lowercase, but it far from ideal

```
import re
mysourceaddrlong = ( repr(data['source_addr_long'])[1:-1] )
```

which outputs `\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\n!\x1c`

```
 mysourceaddrlongUPPERCASE = mysourceaddrlong.upper()
    mysourceaddrlongFIXED = re.sub('[XN]+', lambda m: m.group(0).lower(), mysourceaddrlongUPPERCASE)
```

Comment: Have you tried something? If yes do add some code :)

Comment: what does this have to do with XBee? Or with "hex", at all?

Comment: `mysourceaddrlong = \x00\x13\xa2\x00@\n!\x1c` not python bro

Comment: \x00\x13\xa2\x00@\n!\x1c is the hex address of the xbee I want to talk to AKA the dest_addr_long of the receiving xbee.

Comment: Try something like splitting on backslash, converting each element to `xXXXX`  and reassembe using backslash separation.

Comment: I edited the question to put it more into context

Comment: It's weird (IMHO) that you need the dest_addr_long to be in upper case, but it's ok to mix hex codes with plain chars & escape sequences like `\n`. I would've expected that a "pure" hex string like `\x00\x13\xA2\x00\x40\x0A\x21\x1C` or even just `0013A200400A211C` would be preferred. FWIW, either of those are quite easy to produce in Python from the raw byte data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yoou do not need a RegEx for this at all. You can just use `str` functions

```
>>> mysourceaddrlong = r"\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\n!\x1c"
>>> "\\".join([(i[0]+i[1:].upper()) for i in mysourceaddrlong.split('\\') if i])
'x00\\x13\\xA2\\x00@\\n!\\x1C'
```

Combine the generator expression with a join, and it will work out for you

**EDIT**

Add a `\` in front if you want it to be so

e.g:

```
str = 'x00\\x13\\xA2\\x00@\\n!\\x1C' # what you get
str = "\\"+str
```

Comment: Close, but does not solve the N which is still a capital letter.

Comment: are you sure this works? You are working on s not  mysourceaddrlong

Comment: I don't think you get the output you have in your answer

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Again, Sorry, `s` was actually `mysourceaddrlong.split('\\')`

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham (You're damn good, you help everyone rectify their answers, unlike a few other people)

Comment: @BhargavRao, the output is now x00\x13\xA2\x00@\n!\x1C and not \x00\x13\xA2\x00@\n!\x1C. If I simply join a \ to the front, for some reason I don't end up with a valid 8 byte long value. I suspect it has something to with raw strings vs literal strings. Still working on it

Comment: @itzzitzz Add a  \  in front .. ;)

Comment: I'm happy with that. Thanks @BhargavRao.